# clang showing incorrect target on M1 Mac

Tags: command-line

When I run `clang --version` I get this result:

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

But I'm currently running on an M1 mac, so this should be returning some sort of arm64. I just reinstalled my command line tools to try and fix this but no change. What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Is Terminal or the shell running in Rosetta? What does running `arch` return?

Comment: @nohillside good q. I previously did have it running through Rosetta. I disabled that, but to answer your question `arch` is returning `i386`

Comment: @nohillside phew okay I rebooted and now `arch` returns `arm64` and clang returns `arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0`

Answer (score 1):

You have either Terminal or the shell running with Rosetta (as indicated by the output of `arch`). Change this to run natively and you will get `clang` to compile to ARM.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution. I had unselected rosetta in the settings I just needed to remember to reboot